# security : is this method reliable to ensure a HTTP request comes from my app and not from third party

Tags: http, security

I'm implementing 2FA on my app with phone number verification. As SMS are not free, I really need to ensure that a request to my server comes from my app and not from any third party http request launcher.

For this purpose, I thought about encrypting the http request with a key provided by my server within my app, and send that encrypted request. As my app is a binary (this is not applicable for web of course), I was thinking it would be difficult to see the encrypting method. The process would be the following :

- my app asks my server a key
- my server generates, stores and returns a random key
- app encrypt the whole actual request with a "secret" method, depending on that key (secret = in binary so hardly readable)
- app send to server the encrypted request + the key
- The server sees if the key exists, and tries to decrypt the request. If it manages to decrypt, it proceed the request, and then remove the key from its storage so no one can use it anymore.

I don't see any to compromise this system, except if someone manage to read from apple/android binary app the encrypting system the app uses.

**Do you think this can be a good process ? Do you see any way to compromise this system ? Is reading from a binary file is really difficult ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start with the flaws in your design, from an android perspective, even if you have enabled pro-guard for your app, we can still decompile the app and trace back the api calls

- If your server is not using HTTPS - its easy to trace the calls going
  back to the backend server by routing through a proxy server like
  charles proxy, and analysing the response, even if you are using
  https its possible to install ssl certificates to trust the proxy and
  get the response. Also by analyzing the outbound requests its
  possible to extract the signed key from the app
- Its easy to decompile an apk package and opening it in IDEs and
  searching for the backend server url by inputting 'api' or
  'http','https' keywords on the ide project search window
- If you are storing the secrets in shared preferences or storage, it
  can be read from the device ,if the attacker has root access to file
  system.

  *then remove the key from its storage so no one can use it anymore.*
  For the above scenario, i will run the app and once it stores the key , i can change the permission to read only , so even if the app tries to remove it , it wont be deleted

You can use SSL-Pinning, and putting the keys in compiled libraries making it difficult for the attacker to decrypt the key, also you need to make sure that you don't create any other loop holes

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I meant, the server removes the key from its server storage (on server side database), so once a key + a encrypted request is sent, no one can send the encrypted request anymore again. Is SSL pinning preventing any third party to send http request too ? Is it absolutely reliable ?

Comment: my app asks my server a key - how do you ensure that the request is coming from your app , as per your strategy, you will be generating the key for each and every request (correct me if im wrong), ssl pinning and all other methods will make the attacker difficult to crack you app and it also comes with its own disadvantages where you need to update the app whenever you need to change your certificate,

Comment: 1/ no problem if an attacker ask a server key as it cannot encrypt the request with it, it would be a « public key » 2/for my purpose no problem of performance, I wanted to use this system only for 2FA, as I don’t want anyone able to send SMS request to my server as I pay these SMS 3/ do you think in my case I should use « SSL pinning » ?

Comment: for 1, its possible to decompile and reverse engineer the logic to encrypt the data, i would recommend you to use ssl pinning

Comment: :-) glad i was able to help

Answer (score 0):

You may also share the common key between app and server through alternate channel , like an email . Where the user once he registers for the App gets and Email with a QR code which once scanned will give the server key. The security of this approach is tied to the secure access of the email by authorized user.

You may them follow the standard approach of sending the encrypted request to server to verify the phone number , once done you may delete the data form your app storage.